# /tmp usage in linux

Tags: linux, temporary-files, tmp

How I can find out how much /tmp space is required by an application. Generally sometime I see /tmp is full and get error saying not able to write to /tmp. So is there any way to find out how much /tmp space is required by an application ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way. Programs use /tmp on an ad-hoc basis.